# canvas arc() in js has a larger hidden radius than what is actually shown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a pseudo-pong game [here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvcwx35u/3/). The problem I'm having is that it seems like there's an extra, wider radius on the circle than what I can actually see. I'm using the `plane.arc()` method to draw the circle, and I don't know how I can actually fix my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was using size (=100) to detect collisions but using arcsize (=20) to draw ball. Change value of size from 100 to 20. Remove the arcsize declaration. Change arcsize to size in the arc function call. Then the game should work.

Note that in code for bouncing ball off top and left walls, the code is using the center of the ball. That code needs to account for ball size.